# Spliting layers from multispectral images

Tags: arcmap, raster, arcgis-desktop

I have an image with 4 bands and I wanted to De-layer stack to have each bands separately. How and with which software I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Composite Bands](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Composite_Bands/00170000009p000000/) tool of ArcGIS for Desktop to extract the bands. Navigate to your image file, double click and select a raster band to export.